# simple Tk application - draw on the click of a button

Tags: python, canvas, python-3.x, tkinter, tk-toolkit

Can anyone tell me why my 'addLine' method is failing to call when the self.rec button is clicked?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
root = Tk()

class Paint:
    def __init__(self, parent):
        self.parent = parent
        self.whiteBoard = Canvas(self.parent)
        self.whiteBoard.grid(column=0, row=0, sticky=(N,W,E,S))
        self.lastx = 0
        self.lasty = 0
        self.rec = self.whiteBoard.create_rectangle((10, 10, 30, 30), fill="red")
        self.whiteBoard.tag_bind(self.rec, "<Button-1>", self.getClick)

    def xy(self, event):
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y
        print (event.x, " is the x coordinate")
        print (event.y, " is the y coordinate")

    def addLine(self, event):
        canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y))
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y

    def getClick(self, event):
        self.whiteBoard.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
        self.whiteBoard.bind("B1-Motion>", self.addLine)

white = Paint(root)

root.mainloop()
```

This is all part of an attempt to make a MS paint clone using Tkinter.

Comment: There is no need to use `lambda` here. `self.whiteBoard.tag_bind(self.rec, "<Button-1>", self.getClick)` or `self.whiteBoard.tag_bind(self.rec, "<Button-1>", lambda x: self.getClick(x))

Comment: @mmgp -- Looks like an answer to me.  Post it :)

Comment: @mmgp If I add this 'addLine' method, I expect to be able to start drawing.  Could you possibly tell me why it's not working?

Comment: `def addLine(self, event):
        canvas.create_line((lastx, lasty, event.x, event.y))
        self.lastx, self.lasty = event.x, event.y

    def getClick(self, event):
        self.whiteBoard.bind("<Button-1>", self.xy)
        self.whiteBoard.bind("B1-Motion>", self.addLine)`

Comment: edit:  Just updated the question, please take a look!

Answer (score 0):

First, you are binding to `B1-Motion>` (note the missing `<`). But, more importantly, don't do bindings like those. It looks like the `getClick` method is actually "select the line tool". Then, add the bindings `<Button-1>` and `<B1-Motion>` to the canvas itself. When the callbacks are called, you do the actions according to the selected tool.

Here is rough sketch that follows this suggestion (with a `RECTANGLE` tool as a bonus):

```
import tkinter

# TOOLS
LINE, RECTANGLE = list(range(2))

class Paint:
    def __init__(self, canvas):
        self.canvas = canvas
        self._tool, self._obj = None, None
        self.lastx, self.lasty = None, None
        self.canvas.bind('<Button-1>', self.update_xy)
        self.canvas.bind('<B1-Motion>', self.draw)

    def draw(self, event):
        if self._tool is None or self._obj is None:
            return
        x, y = self.lastx, self.lasty
        if self._tool in (LINE, RECTANGLE):
            self.canvas.coords(self._obj, (x, y, event.x, event.y))

    def update_xy(self, event):
        if self._tool is None:
            return
        x, y = event.x, event.y
        if self._tool == LINE:
            self._obj = self.canvas.create_line((x, y, x, y))
        elif self._tool == RECTANGLE:
            self._obj = self.canvas.create_rectangle((x, y, x, y))
        self.lastx, self.lasty = x, y

    def select_tool(self, tool):
        print('Tool', tool)
        self._tool = tool

class Tool:
    def __init__(self, whiteboard, parent=None):
        self.whiteboard = whiteboard

        frame = tkinter.Frame(parent)
        self._curr_tool = None
        for i, (text, t) in enumerate((('L', LINE), ('R', RECTANGLE))):
            lbl = tkinter.Label(frame, text=text, width=2, relief='raised')
            lbl._tool = t
            lbl.bind('<Button-1>', self.update_tool)
            lbl.pack(padx=6, pady=6*(i % 2))
        frame.pack(side='left', fill='y', expand=True, pady=6)

    def update_tool(self, event):
        lbl = event.widget
        if self._curr_tool:
            self._curr_tool['relief'] = 'raised'
        lbl['relief'] = 'sunken'
        self._curr_tool = lbl
        self.whiteboard.select_tool(lbl._tool)


root = tkinter.Tk()

canvas = tkinter.Canvas(highlightbackground='black')
whiteboard = Paint(canvas)
tool = Tool(whiteboard)
canvas.pack(fill='both', expand=True, padx=6, pady=6)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Sorry to bother you again, but could you give me some pointers on how to create a couple of new tools, which draw ovals and rectangles?  I've been trying and I'm just ending up with more lines.  I added a new button for drawing rectangles and updated the 'update_xy' method to include recs ie         `elif self._tool == RECTANGLE:
            self._obj = self.canvas.create_rectangle((self.lastx, self.lasty, x, y))`  But I'm still drawing lines.  Does this have something to do with the coordinates necessitating a line?

Comment: @user2038497 it seems we are going nowhere. Each time a problem is solved you create another one, in the same question.

Comment: @user2038497 see the updated answer, note that this makes your other questions duplicates of this one.

Comment: @mmpg Sorry, I wasn't aware of this part of posting etiquette.  Thanks for your help.